# python import names file and sort alphabetically

Tags: python, file, while-loop

I can't figure out why my simple names script will not work. It appears to bug out on the while loop. I might be calling it wrongly, but I figured I might try to get an answer here while I continue researching.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

#open the file
name_file = open('names.txt', 'r')

#read in lines
names = name_file.readlines()

#close file
name_file.close()

#loop to place names in array
index = 0
        while index < len(names):
             names[index] = names[index].rstrip('\n')
             index += 1
#sort
names.sort()

#print sorted names
print names
```

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: For future reference, writing a `while` loop this way is extra work, and very easy to get wrong. Just do `for index in range(len(name)):` or, even better, `for index, name in enumerate(names):`. (Or, maybe even better, turn the whole thing into a list comprehension or genexpr.)

Comment: As another side note, it's better to use `with open('names.txt') as name_file:` than explicit `close`, and [there is almost never a good reason to call `readlines()`](http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html).

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this works:

```
with open ('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    names = sorted (name.rstrip ('\n') for name in f)

print (names)
```

The `with` takes care of closing the file once you leaf the scope.

Comment: I'm an idiot. I don't know what I was trying to accomplish with the loop, but I removed it and it works as designed.\

Comment: You are not an idiot. You are learning and this is the important part. You cannot learn from successes, you learn from errors. Either from your own, or from others'.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Why did you add all those extra spaces all over the place? The OP is writing nice PEP8-style code; it's probably not a good idea to encourage him to do otherwise.

Comment: I don't like PEP8-style. That's all. Sorry there. But I took into consideration your info about `strip` and `rstrip`.

Comment: Actually I really don't want to encourage any coding-style. Nor advocate pro or contra any style. I just want to use myself the style I personally prefer.

Answer (score -1):

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as f:
    names = sorted(f.readlines())

for (i, name) in enumerate(names):
    names[i] = name.rstrip('\n')
```

This should do the trick.

There is always better to use a for-loop for these kind of things.

Comment: This doesn't work; where does the `i` come from? (Also, why are you adding extra semicolons to code that didn't have them or need them?)

Comment: oh, as you can see i am not very used to python. i will correct this answer

Comment: Jocke, you might want to look here: http://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: @Hyperboreus Yes I know what list-comprehensions are and how to use them. But I do not use python that much to say when to actually use them. There are list-comprehensions in Haskell too, and they are used very rarely.